# Need third party Business Calendar API

Tags: java, soa, jdeveloper, wli

I am working on  a work flow project, usually Business calendar is a part of suite. 
 but We do not have license for that.

Can any one suggest any third part Business calendar API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Calendar API

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/